# What does “cut the record” here mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> New single “Happiness” boasts a few extra layers of 1975-ness that Healy fave Charlie Kaufman could appreciate. The song is based on a demo by the cult dance-pop producer DJ Sabrina the Teenage DJ, who embedded a slowed-down sample of an old Healy interview into the track. Talking about that sample of himself, mid-chew, Healy says, “I didn’t know that was me until we fucking **cut the record**! I just thought it was a guy who’s got a weird English accent.”

I want to know what **“cut the record”** means in this case. Is it saying that he didn’t realize it was him until they made the album on Vinyl or CD?

Comment: a. To record a performance on (a phonograph record or other medium).
b. To make a recording of (a song, for example).  [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cut+(album)#:~:text=25.-,a.,a%20song%2C%20for%20example).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, "cut" would mean to sing for a recording, as in these definitions:

From Merriam-Webster:

> **cut** *transitive verb*
> **5 b
>
> (1) :** to sing, play, or act for the recording of
> *// cut an album
>
> // cut a commercial*
> **(2) :** to sing or play (a song, a track, etc.) for a studio recording

But it obviously wasn't possible for Healy to notice that his voice had been added to the track before he'd even recorded it, so it can't have that meaning. From the context, it seems he means he didn't notice it was him until after the album was *published*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I’m a bit confused. The album is not out yet. Does it might mean he didn’t realize until he listened to the song on the album?

Comment: Yes, he must have listened to the finished product after the recording process was complete. (Incidentally, _cut_ goes back to the early years of acoustic recording, when the grooves of the master disc were literally cut into it.)